# Geometry Nodes - How to get size (X,Y) information from Image Texture node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to use the size of an image to drive the size of a grid?

I tried to do the following:

[image]

But it doesn't work, obviously, because you can't share a diamond socket with a circle.

Is there a way to extract the size coordinates from the Image Texture?

Comment: The Node Image Texture does not output a size, but a color value. However, it can receive a vector that ranges from (0, 0, 0) to (1, 1, 1). An input of the Node Grid requires a single value, but you are trying to apply a field with multiple values here. What do you actually want to do? Please tell us more about it....

Comment: I want to create a grid that is the exact same size as the image (e.g. 1920 x 1080), then map the image to the grid, and then manipulate it.  In other words, kind of like what the "Images As Planes" plugin does, but with Geometry Nodes.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Size is relative, but aspect ratio is not. But unfortunately no, in *Geometry Nodes* you can't find out the size or aspect ratio of an image.

Comment: Does it have to be done with GN? I feel like this is a **Python** and possibly also **driver** question. If you're okay with solutions using those methods, I suggest putting those tags on your question. I'll leave it up to you to decide.

Comment: @Mentalist I agree, however, this should then become a new question, as it makes little sense to "bend" an existing question with an accepted answer in another direction.

Comment: I don't know Python, I've never used drivers, so I was just curious if it was possible to do it with GM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Blender < 3.5

No, with *Geometry Nodes* alone it is unfortunately in no way possible to determine the dimensions of an image.

An image does not have any "geometry" and therefore cannot be processed in this way.

Conversely, however, it is possible to read the data of an image on the basis of a position.

This would make it possible, at least in a roundabout way, to find out the aspect ratio of an image (as long as it does not consist of black pixels). However, the usefulness of this offense is to be seriously questioned.

### Blender 3.5+

The `Image Info` node has finally arrived in a stable version of Blender ([Release Notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.5/Nodes_Physics)):

*"A new **Image Info** node allows retrieving various information about an image ([rBefcd587bc28d](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/efcd587bc28d))"*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I accept this answer as conclusive based on what I've gathered here and elsewhere.  I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using two value nodes and using a driver for each node

```
To add driver right-click on value field and choose add driver
use these expressions for x and y dimensions
bpy.data.images["image.jpg"].size[0]   //x-size
bpy.data.images["image.jpg"].size[1]   //y-size
```

This will get the size info into your set-up

To size the grid you can use transform node
The actual image will have to be dropped into the material for the object.
Or you can set it up in a shader node.  I'm new to this as well...so the way I do things is geometry stuff (scaling etc) goes in geometry node and coloring stuff goes in shader node.

[image: Scale image to texture size in geometry node]